# Android BLE. device.getUUids() always return null

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I m trying to scan for BLE devices and filter the result with my devices UUIDs only.

I have used the google sample code from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/cefd49aae65dc85161d08419494071d74ffb982f/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/src/com/example/bluetooth/le/DeviceScanActivity.java)

It does find the devices and list them.

but when I try to filter by my UUIDs the method device.getUuids() always return null instead of returning a valid array with the device's UUID.

```
 private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
        new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                List<String> uuids = new ArrayList<String>();
                uuids.add("MY_VALID_UID");
                ParcelUuid[] deviceUuids = device.getUuids();
                // this if is never exeuted device deviceUuids is always null.
                if (deviceUuids != null) {
                    for (ParcelUuid uuid : device.getUuids()) {
                        if (uuids.contains(uuid.toString())) {
                            mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
                            mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                }
}
        });
    }
};
```

I have also tried passing my uuids as a filter to the startLEScan method as follow, but no results are being returned.

```
        String s = "MY_UUID";
        String s2 = s.replace("-", "");
        UUID uuid = new UUID(
                new BigInteger(s2.substring(0, 16), 16).longValue(),
                new BigInteger(s2.substring(16), 16).longValue());
        System.out.println(uuid);
        UUID[] uuids = {uuid};
        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(uuids, mLeScanCallback);
```

OR

```
UUID.fromString("MY UUID");
```

A

Comment: Maybe this is somehow related
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67521

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways for a central application to know service UUIDs supported by a beacon.

One way is to extract information from advertisement packets that beacons emit. But if beacons do not emit such packets (e.g. packets whose AD type is 0x03), a central application cannot get information about service UUIDs by this way.

The other way is to connect a target beacon and explicitly require information about service UUIDs supported by the beacon.

[JavaDoc of getUuids()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#getUuids()) method says as follows:

> This method does not start a service discovery procedure to retrieve the UUIDs from the remote device. Instead, the local cached copy of the service UUIDs are returned.

So, (1) if a beacon does not emit packets which include information about service UUIDs and (2) if you have not required the beacon to return information about service UUIDs (e.g. if you have not performed 'service discovery'), getUuids() returns null.